# How to find whether specific number of continuous consecutive numbers are contains in a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I want to know whether a string contains 5 or more continuous consecutive numbers.

```
var a = "ac39270982"; // False
var a = "000223344998"; // False
var a = "512345jj7"; // True - it contains 12345
var a = "aa456780"; // True - it contains 45678
```

Is there a RegEx available to accomplish this?  Would it also be able to work in the following situation?

```
var a = "5111213141587"; // True
```

This should be true because it contains 11,12,13,14,15.

I'm not sure if it is possible to check the provided examples (single-digit, double-digit numbers) as well as larger numbers (triple-digit, etc.).

Comment: Checking (without regex) of the multiples is not too hard: ROUND(string.length/5) gives you the maximum possible number of digits. Why use regex though?

Comment: How do you know if it is `11,12,13,14,15` and not `11,1,2,...`?

Comment: You can't do this with regular expressions alone.

Comment: @chris85 I think the OP is asking for an algorithm that's capable of finding both single- and multi-digit cases. i.e. if there exists a way to split the input string such that you find one of these sequences, then return true.

Comment: @firos should the answer return true for sequences like `7891011`, because they can be split into `7,8,9,10,11`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function NstreamsOfNumberN (str) {
    
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        
        let numBeingConsidered = Number(str[i]);
                
        let numOfComparisonsToBeDone = numBeingConsidered - 1;
        
        for (let j = i; j < numOfComparisonsToBeDone + i; j++) {
                
            if (str[j] != str[j+1]) {break}//compare neigbourin nums

            else if ((j - i + 1) === numOfComparisonsToBeDone)  
            { let theNwithNstreams = numBeingConsidered
              return [str, (theNwithNstreams), true]} 

        //(j - i + 1) equals num of comparisons that has been done.
        }
    }
    return [str,null,false]
}

NstreamsOfNumberN('334775555583444582')

9 streams of the number 9 
8 streams of the number 8 
7 streams of the number 7 ...
3 streams of the number 3
2 streams of the number 2.
```

Answer (score 3):

I took the time to make a 100% Javascript approach to your question. I made it to simply parse each character in the string and do integer only comparison. This works not only for five consecutive integers, but it works for checking for tenths as well (10's, 20's, etc). You can also increase/decrease the number of comparisons if you wish.

A fair warning: despite this method being potentially scalable if coded to look for all kinds of numeric sizes, you'd still be bound by computing power and number of comparisons. That is why I only provided the code for single digits and tenths, I leave it open to you/the community to decide how to expand from here.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/9shz7j9u/)

If you happen to need more details about how it works then let me know, I can further clarify its inner workings.

```
var str = "1111122asdgas222*&^%121314151617bdjfjahdi234bdce56789";
var consecutive = 5; // Number of comparisons

// Single digits
alert("It is " + consecutiveDigits(str, consecutive) + " that " + str + " contains " + consecutive + " consecutive digits.");
// Tenths digits
alert("It is " + consecutiveDigits(str, consecutive) + " that " + str + " contains " + consecutive + " consecutive tenths.");

function consecutiveDigits(str, consecutive){
    var curr,
        prev,
        count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        curr = parseInt(str.split('')[i]);
        if(isNumeric(curr)) {
            if(count === 0){
                ++count;
            }
            else if(prev + 1 === curr){
                ++count;
                if(count === consecutive){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            prev = curr;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function consecutiveTenths(str, consecutive, iterations){
    var curr,
        prev,
        curr_tenth = 0,
        prev_tenth = 0,
        count = 0,
        count_tenth = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        curr = parseInt(str.split('')[i]);
        if(isNumeric(curr)) {
            ++count;
            if(count === iterations){
                curr_digit = (prev * 10) + curr;
                alert(count_digit + " " + curr_digit + " " + prev_tenth);
                if(count_digit === 0){
                    ++count_digit;
                }
                else if(curr_tenth === (prev_tenth + 1)){
                    ++count_digit;
                    if(count_digit === consecutive){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                prev_digit = curr_digit;
                count = 0;
            }
            else {
                prev = curr;
            }
        }
        else {
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}


function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build regexp that will validate if it's true or not, but you might have a hard time retrieving the whole consecutive string. That said the RegExp will be a bit cumbersome, but you can create a function to create the regexp needed, depending on parameters wanted. See snippet:

```js
function build_regexp(n) {
  var string = "";
  for (var i = 0; i <= 14 - n; i++) {
    var start_num = i
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      string += (start_num++).toString()

    }
    string += "|";
  }
  string = string.replace(/\|$/, '');
  return string
}


document.getElementById('check').onclick = function() {
  var regex = new RegExp(build_regexp(document.getElementById('cons').value), "g");
  document.getElementById('regex').textContent = regex;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = (regex.exec(document.getElementById('to_check').value) || "false")
}
```

```html
<div id="regex"></div>
<div>Enter wanted consecutive numbers: <input id="cons"></input></div>
<div>Enter string to check: <input id="to_check"></input></div>
<button id="check">check</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: Added a code snippet & fixed bug in numRegex**

To answer the general case (i.e. contiguous sequence of arbitrary-length digits), you can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ksgLzL9u/8/

```js
/* Find a sequence of n > 1 contiguously increasing integers in input
 * 
 * If sequence is found, return an object:
 *   {
 *     start:  <starting index of the sequence in input>,
 *     length: <length of the found sequence string>,
 *     first:  <first number in the sequence>
 *   }
 *
 * Otherwise, return null
 */
function findSequence(input, n) {
  var numRegex = /^(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/;

  // Try every starting position
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
    // At the current starting position, try every length for the 1st number
    for (var firstLen = 1; i + firstLen < input.length - 1; ++firstLen) {
      var afterFirst = i + firstLen;
      var first = input.slice(i, afterFirst);
      
      // If the first string isn't an integer, move on
      if (!numRegex.test(first)) {
        continue;
      }

      // Convert the first string to an integer
      var firstInt = parseInt(first, 10);

      // Build what the rest of the string should look like following the
      // first, in order to get a valid sequence
      var rest = "";
      for (var j = 1; j < n; ++j) {
        rest = rest.concat(firstInt + j);
      }

      // Compare to what actually follows the starting string; if it
      // matches, then we have our sequence; otherwise, continue on
      if (input.slice(afterFirst, afterFirst + rest.length) === rest) {
          return {
            start: i,
            length: first.length + rest.length,
            first: first
          };
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}

$(function() {
  function processChange() {
    var input = $('#input').val();
    var n = parseInt($('#n').val());
      
    if (n > 1 && input.length) {
      var result = findSequence(input, n);
      if (result) {
        $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
        var afterFirst = result.start + result.first.length;
        var afterSeq = result.start + result.length;
        $('#highlighted').empty()
          .append($('<span/>')
                    .text(input.slice(0, result.start)))
          .append($('<span/>')
                    .addClass('sequence')
                    .append($('<span/>')
                              .addClass('first')
                              .text(result.first))
                    .append($('<span/>')
                              .text(input.slice(afterFirst, afterSeq))))
          .append($('<span/>')
                    .text(input.slice(afterSeq)));
      } else {
        $('#result').text("No sequence found");
        $('#highlighted').empty();
      }
    } else {
      $('#result').text("");
      $('#highlighted').empty();
    }
  }
  
  $('input,n').on("keyup mouseup", processChange);
  processChange();
});
```

```css
#input {
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 200px;
}

#n {
    width: 50px;
}

.highlighted-result {
    font-family: monospace;
}

.highlighted-result .sequence {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.highlighted-result .first {
    border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Input</h1>
<div>
  <input id="input" type="text" value="111121314155" placeholder="input">
  <input id="n" type="number" value="5" placeholder="n">
</div>
<h1>Results</h1>
<div id="highlighted" class="highlighted-result"></div>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

I haven't attempted to optimize the solution (e.g. the `firstLen` iteration can be short-circuited, and the entire `rest` string doesn't need to be built up), but I left as-is to make the algorithm clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to do this with regex, but here is a tentative:

- One digit

  ```
  (?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)){4,}\d
  ```

  https://regex101.com/r/mw4bvG/1
- Two digits

  ```
  (?:(\d)(?:0(?=(?:\1)1)|1(?=(?:\1)2)|2(?=(?:\1)3)|3(?=(?:\1)4)|4(?=(?:\1)5)|5(?=(?:\1)6)|6(?=(?:\1)7)|7(?=(?:\1)8)|8(?=(?:\1)9))|09(?=10)|19(?=20)|29(?=30)|39(?=40)|49(?=50)|59(?=60)|69(?=70)|79(?=80)|89(?=90)){4,}\d{2}
  ```

  https://regex101.com/r/Kcl9FC/1
- Three digits

  ```
  (?:(\d{2})(?:0(?=(?:\1)1)|1(?=(?:\1)2)|2(?=(?:\1)3)|3(?=(?:\1)4)|4(?=(?:\1)5)|5(?=(?:\1)6)|6(?=(?:\1)7)|7(?=(?:\1)8)|8(?=(?:\1)9))|(\d)(?:09(?=(?:\2)10)|19(?=(?:\2)20)|29(?=(?:\2)30)|39(?=(?:\2)40)|49(?=(?:\2)50)|59(?=(?:\2)60)|69(?=(?:\2)70)|79(?=(?:\2)80)|89(?=(?:\2)90))|099(?=100)|199(?=200)|299(?=300)|399(?=400)|499(?=500)|599(?=600)|699(?=700)|799(?=800)|899(?=900)){4,}\d{3}
  ```

  https://regex101.com/r/joeWdR/1
- All together

  ```
  (?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)){4,}\d|(?:(\d)(?:0(?=(?:\1)1)|1(?=(?:\1)2)|2(?=(?:\1)3)|3(?=(?:\1)4)|4(?=(?:\1)5)|5(?=(?:\1)6)|6(?=(?:\1)7)|7(?=(?:\1)8)|8(?=(?:\1)9))|09(?=10)|19(?=20)|29(?=30)|39(?=40)|49(?=50)|59(?=60)|69(?=70)|79(?=80)|89(?=90)){4,}\d{2}|(?:(\d{2})(?:0(?=(?:\2)1)|1(?=(?:\2)2)|2(?=(?:\2)3)|3(?=(?:\2)4)|4(?=(?:\2)5)|5(?=(?:\2)6)|6(?=(?:\2)7)|7(?=(?:\2)8)|8(?=(?:\2)9))|(\d)(?:09(?=(?:\3)10)|19(?=(?:\3)20)|29(?=(?:\3)30)|39(?=(?:\3)40)|49(?=(?:\3)50)|59(?=(?:\3)60)|69(?=(?:\3)70)|79(?=(?:\3)80)|89(?=(?:\3)90))|099(?=100)|199(?=200)|299(?=300)|399(?=400)|499(?=500)|599(?=600)|699(?=700)|799(?=800)|899(?=900)){4,}\d{3}
  ```

  https://regex101.com/r/NyCLh6/1